# Cake PHP delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash with custom validation rule

Tags: php, cakephp, validation, cakephp-2.0

I have an issue I´d like to adress to you.
I´ve set up a custom validation rule within the appmodel in class post.

```
'DELIVERYAREA' => array(
        'rule-1' => array(
            'rule' => array('between', 5, 5),
            'message' => 'Bitte eine fünfstellige Postleitzahl eingeben'
        ),
        'rule-2' => array(
            'rule' => 'numeric',
            'message' => 'Bitte nur Zahlen eingeben'
        ),
        'rule-3' => array(
            'rule' => 'ZipExists',
            'message' => 'Postleitzahl existiert nicht!'            
        )
    )
```

The function ZipExists is coded in the appmodel too but in class zipcode.

```
public function ZipExists($zipcode){
$valid = $this->find('count', array('conditions'=> array('Zipcode.zipcode' =>$zipcode)));
if ($valid >= 1){
  return true;
}
else{
  return false;
}
}
```

debug($valid) throws the correct numbers: 1 if the function finds a valid zipcode and 0 if not. That said means the function is called properly.
But what Cake does are two things.
First it throws an error: Delimiter mustn´t be alphanumeric or backslash. Since trying with array_push($zipcode); in the function didn´t work I don´t have a clue on that.

Second the error message in the view for the Deliveryarea is shown all the time, doesn´t matter if the function threw true or false.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first two validation rules can be replaced with the `postal` validation, it also supports validation of German postal codes; http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation::postal however, I suspect the error message may be cause by another validation rule and CakePhp interprets that as a regular expression. Have you tried to disable all other validation rules to narrow down the problem?

Comment: Disabling all others changed nothing. I get the error that Cake couldn´t find the validation handler for zipexists again after building in the postal-function you mentioned: 'DELIVERYAREA' => array(
           'rule-1' => array(
    'rule' => array('postal', null, 'de'),
    'message' => 'Bitte eine gültige Postleitzahl eingeben.',
    'last' => true
   ),
   'rule-2' => array(
    'rule' => array('ZipExists'),
    'message' => 'Postleitzahl existiert nicht!'            
            )
        )

Comment: After reading and debugging a lot I strongly presume that Cake wants the custom function "ZipExists" in the post-class - the class where it is called. But I need to call that function while it being existing in class Zipcode. But the book and the web to this time have nothing to offer on this topic. Maybe I only had bad luck on finding info?!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Cake wants the custom validation rules to be in the certain class where the rule is called. So, when you call a custom rule in class post, the custom function has to be written down in class post, otherwise cake won´t find it and validate it to false everytime.

The magic to do here is to import the appmodel-class you want to use in the class you call the validation-function. That works with the following statement:

$Zipcode = ClassRegistry::init('Class to use - in my case "Zipcode"');

But if your tables are associated with each other with hasAny or belongsTo and stuff, the custom functions works without that. Another important point you mustn´t miss is, that all validation functions has to be introduced with "public function xyz" otherwise cake won´t find them too.